# Prolog rotate list N times in either direction

Tags: prolog

So my objective here is to write a predicate that rotates a list to the right N times if N>0 or the left N times if N<0.  Here is my code so far, the output is false unless N == 0 and I am not sure where my issue is.

```
rotateleft([L|R], N) :-
   append(R, [L], N).

rotateright(L, R) :-
   rotateleft(R, L).

rotate(L,N,R) :-
   (  N = 0 ->
      R = L
   ;  N > 0 ->
      rotateright(L,R),
      N is N-1,
      rotate(L,N,R)
   ;  N < 0,
      rotateleft(L,R),
      N is N+1,
      rotate(L,N,R)
   ).
```

Comment: Your initial attempt is not sensible.  You have one clause for `rotateleft/2` that restates its logic in terms of `append/3`, commonly used to mean concatenating the first two arguments (lists) into the third argument (again a list).  But your Question suggests that the `N` from `rotateleft/2` will be a number (an integer), not a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
list_rotated(N, Xs, Ys) :-
   maplist(\_^_^true, Xs, Ys),  % or same_length(Xs, Ys)
   length(Xs, M),
   R is -N mod M,
   length(As, R),
   append(As,Bs, Xs),
   append(Bs,As, Ys).
```

Please note that this definition has much better termination behavior. It terminates iff the length of one of the lists is known.

Comment: Thanks for this, I see where it behaves much better than my attempt.